# How to query json data nodes using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I wish to query json result data to be used in Razor view and would like to know how to search by a specific id and capture data for a specific node:

Here is an example(just a part) of my json:

```
{
   "maxPages":1,
   "data":[
      {
         "id":"123",
         "perfomanceData":[
            {
               "platform":{
                  "name":"Test0",
                  "id":0
               }, 
         ],
     {
         "id":"124",
         "perfomanceData":[
            {
               "platform":{
                  "name":"Test1",
                  "id":0
               }, 
         ],
     {
         "id":"125",
         "perfomanceData":[
            {
               "platform":{
                  "name":"Test2",
                  "id":0
               }, 
         ],
```

I wish to search by an ID example 125 and retrieve just this section

```
perfomanceData":[
                {
                   "platform":{
                      "name":"Test2",
                      "id":0
                   }, 
             ]
```

How can I use JavaScript to do the above?

Comment: Please note that the problem has nothing to do with JSON but rather with how to process JS arrays and objects. *How* you got the data is irrelevant (unless you really want to process raw JSON data in JS, i.e. apply string processing, which is probably more complicated than parsing the JSON).

Comment: look into taffyDB, you can turn your json into taffy with one line, then use taffy's query features. if you need something simpler, http://danml.com/js/oquery.js works like oQuery( obj, "[id=125]")...

Comment: Your json is malformed.